# Is there a Yelp equivalent in Ukraine?

Tags: restaurants, ukraine, mobile-apps

I'm looking for a Yelp-like app in Ukraine (at least in Lviv and Kyiv). Since Yelp is not available in Ukraine, what do locals use to search for nearby restaurants and cafes?

If it is possible, I would like a functionality that filters by "open now", like in Yelp.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Locals use [Foursquare](https://foursquare.com) and Google Maps (their venue database has become a lot better in the past years). Yelp is mostly a North American app, I find it to be generally worse than the competition in Europe.

Comment: Oh I see. I have used Google Maps but it is quite inaccurate. So I thought there were something others the locals use...

Comment: @Blaszard don't forget to update Google Maps if you see an error. It's a crowd-sourced system, so it only works if we all do our part :)

Answer (score 3):

It's mostly Google Maps and Facebook where Ukrainians rate places nowadays.

Comment: Yup, at this point Facebook is the #1 reviewing platform right now, with Google is #2.  Yelp has a bit of a barrier-to-entry, so you don't get tend to  casual reviews, you get motivated ones... i.e. Angry ones. As a result Yelp has basically become the "burn book" of the Internet, and regular folks just see a bunch of nerd rage, and don't take it seriously.

Comment: Is it the same if you strip the rating system away? For me it is more than sufficient to have the opening and closing time and location (and maybe the estimated cost).

Comment: @Blaszard: for opening/closing times and location I use http://2gis.ua in Kharkov (just checked - open now filter is there). However the platform does not cover Lviv as far as I can see. Kharkov is extremely detailed, I would expect Kiev to be covered as well. I would not say it's useful for reviews, G Maps is however hardly better in terms of reviews.

Comment: @RomanR. That's good to hear, thanks. Unfortunately I have no plan to visit Kharkov during this trip to Ukraine...

Comment: @Blaszard: I wanted to mentioned that http://2gis.ua/kiev might work out for you in Kiev.